# How to plot biannual data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 2 data points for each year, one for the first half year, one for the second half year. How can I plot them in Matlab? For example:

```
ExampleData = [5; 1; 3; 2; 1; 5]
```

where ExampleData(1) is the value for the first half of 2008, ExampleData(2) is the value for the second half of 2008, ExampleData(3) for the first half of 2009, etc. Matlab datetime command only works for monthly or daily data.

How can I either efficiently transform my data to make plots with axes that make sense, or, the other way round, which type of axis can I use for these biannual data?

Comment: This is way too broad, give us example data etc so we can better help. If you're using Matlab's datetime variable type then you can just plot normally and you don't need to "make the date axis"

Comment: Alright, I added some more detail, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick a start date, for the first data point

```
startdate = datetime(2008, 1, 1); % 1st Jan 2008
```

Then, given your example data, create a datetime vector which has 6 month intervals and matches the length of your data

```
ExampleData = [5; 1; 3; 2; 1; 5];
dates = startdate + calmonths((0:numel(ExampleData)-1)*6);
% dates = [01-Jan-2008, 01-Jul-2008, 01-Jan-2009, 01-Jul-2009, ...]
```

Then plotting is easy

```
plot(dates, ExampleData);          % plot
set(gca, 'xtick', datenum(dates)); % Set x-axis ticks to be fixed 6-monthly
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Comment: Perfect! One follow-up question: how do I change my axis so that it's always labeled with January and July. Because mine is always changing, it starts with November, then September, July, etc...